# How to get a response number of a HTTPS request

Tags: linux, shell, curl, https, wget

I would like to make use of Linux command to get a response number of an HTTPS request rather than HTTP request. According to my current knowledge `wget` and `curl` can achieve the goal.

For instance, given the address https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/vuokrattavat-asunnot/espoo/13874872 I intend to use the following commands:

- with curl: `curl -I https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/vuokrattavat-asunnot/espoo/13874872`
- with wget: `wget --spider -S 'https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/vuokrattavat-asunnot/espoo/13874872'`

Both requests got the response as `HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed`. But when I try the address with a browser, e.g. Chrome, or Firefox etc. The page can indeed display without issue.

Anyone can help on it? How is it possible to get the correct response number rather than the first direct 405?

Comment: elaborate your ***correct** response number*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **`curl`** you need to set `-A, --user-agent` option as some HTTP servers/CGIs require the header `User-Agent` to be filled.

```
curl -I 'https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/vuokrattavat-asunnot/espoo/13874872' -A "Mozilla/5.0"
```

The output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Nov 2017 13:56:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-DB: 5
X-DW: 0
X-DZ: 93.72.75.166
X-VID: 93.72.75.166:14CDB9B4-DE01-3FAA-AFF5-65BC2F771745
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Edge-Control: no-store, bypass-cache
Surrogate-Control: no-store, bypass-cache
```

---

> **`-A, --user-agent <agent string>`**
>                 (HTTP) Specify the User-Agent string to send to the HTTP server. Some badly done CGIs fail if this field  isn't
>                 set  to  `"Mozilla/4.0"`.  To  encode blanks in the string, surround the string with single quote marks. This can
>                 also be set with the `-H, --header` option of course.

Answer (score 0):

The server is answering with HTTP code 405 because it's rejecting the `User-Agent` header your `curl` command sent. This is clearly a bad behaviour from the server configuration or the website application itself. The server should have answered with HTTP 400.

Anyway, the following works fine for the given URL:

```
curl -I -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0" <url>
```